# CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

We are two students that are working on our exam project were we are trying to run TensorFlow on a Raspberry Pi cluster. We are trying to run this example(MNIST), https://github.com/ischlag/distributed-tensorflow-example/blob/master/example.py. (We made some small adjustments were we updated some deprecated procedure calls).

### When we are running the program with our own script:

python /home/alarm/src/tensorflow/tf_mnist_example/examples.py --job_name="ps" --index_data=0 &

for i in {1..7}
do
      ssh -o "BatchMode yes" alarm@rpi0$i python /home/alarm/src/tensorflow/tf_mnist_example/examples.py --job_name="worker" --index_data="$i - 1"

### done

The nodes runs the python script but at the terminal prompt we encountered this error over and over again.
Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job:worker/replica:0/task:0
Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job:worker/replica:0/task:2
Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job:worker/replica:0/task:3
Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job:worker/replica:0/task:4
Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job:worker/replica:0/task:5
Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job:worker/replica:0/task:6

Hope to hear from you
with best regard from sweden.

Answer (score 0):

try setting device filters, that should fix it.

Comment: what are these and where should you set them ?

Answer (score 0):

Those messages means that the workers cannot properly communicate. Verify your network setup (ports and hostnames)